# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" when trying to get a property from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, steam

So, I get my list of Steam games in JSON through the Steam Web API. When I try to get a property from the JSON directly through the Chrome console, it's all good. But when I execute the same line in my code, it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`('x' stands for whatever property I try to get).

```
key = "lotsofrandomnumbersandletters";
id = "steamprofileid";
var gameList = $.getJSON("http://www.corsproxy.com/api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=" + key + "&steamid=" + id + "&format=json");
var gameCount = gameList.responseJSON.response.game_count;
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON()` is asynchronous and you need to access its result in a callback...

```
$.getJSON("http://www.corsproxy.com/api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=" 
        + key + "&steamid=" + id + "&format=json", function (gameList) {
    var gameCount = gameList.responseJSON.response.game_count;
});
```

Comment: I've changed it to this `var key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$.getJSON("http://www.corsproxy.com/api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=" + key + "&steamid=" + id + "&format=json", function(gameList){
 var gameCount = gameList.responseJSON.response.game_count;
});` and it's still giving an error (`Cannot read property 'response'...`). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using Anthony's answer, but declaring `gameCount` outside of `$.getJSON`.